# Creating variables by conditional command in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, panel-data, recode

I have a longitudinal dataset in which people are turning 40 in different years, and I need to do an analysis (propensity score matching) with the 40 year-olds. I want to create an income variable which would use `Income 1992` for people who turn forty in 1998, uses `Income 1994` for people who turn forty in 2000 and so on.

My data looks like this (and I want Incomenew to look like this):

```
  ID | SourceYear| Income1992| Income1994 | Incomenew |
|---------------|------------|------------|           |
| 1  | 1998     |  10000     | 12000      | 10000     |
| 2  | 2000     |  20000     | 15000      | 15000     |
| 3  | 1998     |  17000     | 16000      | 17000     |
| 4  | 2000     |  18000     | 20000      | 20000     |
```

I am interested in their income 6 years before they turn 40. I already adjusted all income variables for the purchasing power of a certain year.I tried this:

```
Incomenew<-NA
Incomenew[SourceYear=="1998"]<-Income1992[SourceYear=="1998"]
Incomenew[SourceYear=="2000"]<-Income1994[SourceYear=="2000"]
```

I get all NAs

I also tried this:

```
`Incomenew<-if (SourceYear=="1998")] {Income1992}
                   else if (SourceYear==2000) 
                 {Income1994}`
```

I get the following error

> Error in if (SourceYear== "1998") { :    argument is of length zero

It would be of great help if someone could help with this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to show a reproducible example.  Also, `Incomenew` is only of length 1 while SourceYear may be of different length.  Try `Incomenew <- rep(NA, length(SourceYear))`

Comment: Unless `SourceYear` is saved as an object useful for subsetting things (I can't tell without data), it likely needs to be prefixed with the dataset: `Income1992[Income1992$SourceYear == 1998,]`. Note you also need to put a comma after it to specify you're subsetting years, and want all columns, and figure out whether your years are strings (`"1998"`) or numbers (`2000`).

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much for your answer, while trying to create a reproducible example, I discovered this command worked; but in my original data it didn't at first. Then I realized it is because I have some NA's in the SourceYear. When I omitted those, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @alistaire Thank you. The dataset was quite large that was why I didn't know how to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my original dataset I had some NA's for the SourceYear. I didn't realize that it was important for this command.
 The first command actually works, if a subset without NA's in the SourceYear is used. An example is:

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
SourceYear<-c("1998", "2000", "1998","2002","2000", "2002", NA)
Income92<-c(100000,120000,170000,180000, 190000, NA)
Income94<-c(120000,150000,160000,20000,NA, 120000)
Income96<-c(130000, 110000,NA, 180000, 190000, 180000)
incomedata<-data.frame(ID, SourceYear,Income92, Income94, Income96, Incomenew)
summary(incomedata)
incomedata1<-subset(incomedata, !is.na(incomedata$SourceYear))
incomedata1$Incomenew<-rep(NA, length(incomedata1$SourceYear))
incomedata1$Incomenew[incomedata1$SourceYear=="1998"]<-
incomedata1$Income92[incomedata1$SourceYear=="1998"]
incomedata1$Incomenew[incomedata1$SourceYear=="2000"]<-
incomedata1$Income94[incomedata1$SourceYear=="2000"]
incomedata1$Incomenew[incomedata1$SourceYear=="2002"]<- 
incomedata1$Income96[SourceYear=="2002"]
```